# Convert date string to date object?

Tags: javascript, string, date, parsing, momentjs

Can someone help me:

I need to create the following.

**Sunday 4 October 08.30 - 10.30 CET**

Underneath this tough, I need to be able to display the local timezone??

Can someone please advise me on the best approach and can I do this with moment.js?

Thanks,

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) There is already a plethora of questions about data parsing with and without moment.js. What have you tried so far? What date(s) *exactly* are you expecting to get?

Comment: What have you tried, and is this a date range?

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to include [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) to figure out what "CET" means. Standard moment does not know how to convert named timezones to offsets.

1. Now, you need to use a regular expression to parse the meaningful pieces of information from your date range.
2. Once you have pulled out the information, reconstruct the pieces into a start and end date string.
3. Parse the date strings relative to the time zone.

I displayed the moment date objects in ISO 8601 format, so they will be in GMT (2 hours behind CET).

```js
const grammar     = /^(\w+) (\d+) (\w+) (\d+\.\d+) - (\d+\.\d+) (\w+)$/;
const inputFormat = 'dddd D MMMM HH.mm'

const input = 'Sunday 4 October 08.30 - 10.30 CET'
const m     = input.match(grammar);

const startDateInput = `${m[1]} ${m[2]} ${m[3]} ${m[4]}`;
const endDateInput   = `${m[1]} ${m[2]} ${m[3]} ${m[5]}`;
const timezone       = m[6];

console.log(`Input (Start Date)  : ${startDateInput}`);
console.log(`Input (End Date)    : ${endDateInput}`);

const startDate = moment.tz(startDateInput, inputFormat, timezone);
const endDate   = moment.tz(endDateInput, inputFormat, timezone);

console.log(`Output (Start Date) : ${startDate.toISOString()}`);
console.log(`Output (End Date)   : ${endDate.toISOString()}`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.31/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure your exact question. You can use JavaScript Date Class.

```
//This will return time, "Mon Aug 10 2020 19:46:31 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
const timeZone = /\((.*)\)/.exec(new Date().toString())[1];

// Here you can calculate offset hours
const offsetHours = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60;

//This is the best way, beacuse sometimes offsethours might be wrong due to daylight saving rules
console.log(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone)
```

[image]
And there are different ways to format a string and for other calculation.
Hope this will solve your problem.